# mapping a @ManyToOne relationship to a basic type

Tags: java, hibernate

My problem is the following. I have a number of items that can be persisted in the database and each item can have a color. I want users that insert new items to be able to see the list of already used colors. This is to prevent one user using the color purple and another user using the color Magenta. Both purple and magenta represent the same color so I want both to use purple. I want to use a @ManyToOne annotation on the string field color because many items can share the same color, however this is only possible for another entity, not for a string. Is there any way where I can have entities reference a color from another table?

Kind regards,

Comment: Sure. Create an entity named Color, mapped to the color table, and use a ManyToOne association to that table.

Comment: Or you can simply use an enum for allowed colors and map it to a basic field

Answer (score 0):

Use the association table to map the entity id and color id so that you can maintain the one to one map here in this table. This allows to avoid the duplicates too as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

I think its better if I just use a SELECT DISTINCT query to retrieve all the colors added so far instead of storing them in a separate color table for easy retrieval. Its allot less fuzz.